# Trying to upload more than 600mb file to server using Qt app

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to develop file uploader using Qt. Here is my code :

```
    QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QByteArray line;
    QFile file(//path);
    while(!file.atEnd())
    {
        line.append(file.readLine());
    }
    file.close();

    QObject::connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(error_On_File_Send(QNetworkReply *)));
    manager->post(request, line);
```

it works ok for small files. But it is not working in large file and gives std:bad_alloc error. What should i do

Comment: Don't try to read in the whole file before you start sending any of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QNetworkAccessManager::post ( const QNetworkRequest & request, QIODevice * data )`. It will automaticly read data when it is needed from any QIODevice. QFile is QIODevice so you should only slightly change your code. Note that you have to manage attached QIODevice by yourself (delete it after `finished()` signal)